# What does it mean that Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime.CoreCLR package is not installed in a .NET core project?

Tags: .net-core, coreclr

I'm trying to get my head around the low level of .NET core to understand what is going on, 
I know that CoreCLR provide the garbage collector, JIT compiler, base .NET types, and other low-level classes, which eventually imply that it is part of any running application.
When I looked for it in an ASP.NET Core project, I found it's not installed, moreover, it's [available for download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WM3LC.png) as a NuGet package.
Then I found this interesting part in the README file of the [CoreCLR](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr) repository:

> But the main reason you can't do much with CoreCLR is that ALL of the types in the class library LOOK like they are defined by the CoreFX framework and not CoreCLR. Any library code defined here lives in a single DLL called System.Private.CoreLib.dll and as its name suggests is private (hidden). Instead for any particular PUBLIC type defined in CoreCLR, we found the 'right' package in CoreFX where it naturally belongs and use that package as its public publishing point. That 'facade' package then forwards references to the (private) implementation in System.Private.CoreLib.dll defined here. For example the System.Runtime package defined in CoreFX declares the PUBLIC name for types like System.Object and System.String. Thus from an applications point of view these types live in System.Runtime.dll. However, System.Runtime.dll (defined in the CoreFX repo) forwards references ultimately to System.Private.CoreLib.dll which is defined here

What I understand from it (not sure), is that every type in CoreCLR (like `String`) is defined twice, one in the CoreCLR (the actual definition), and the other in the CoreFX, which is *facade* definition, that eventually points to the packaged CoreCLR (System.Private.CoreLib.dll), and that the pakage Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime.CoreCLR that shows up in NuGet, isn't useful beacuse I only can access it through the CoreFX.

I hope someone either confirm that or correct me.

Comment: “When I looked for it in an ASP.NET Core project, I found it's not installed.” What makes you feel like that? Any fact to support this statement? About type forwarding, your understand is not correct. Forwarding is done by certain attributes, which you can explore via a tool like ILSpy, so literally such types are not "defined twice", but only once.

Comment: Type forwarding can be found in tons of posts, like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/type-forwarding-in-the-common-language-runtime and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davbr/2009/09/30/type-forwarding/

Comment: @LexLi what makes me feel like that, that the `Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime.CoreCLR` shows up in NuGet as not-installed package, I already attached a link to an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WM3LC.png)